# semantic interoperability and upper ontology

Tags: programming-languages, artificial-intelligence, theory, semantics, linguistics

what is the relation between semantic interoperability and upper ontology?

Comment: `grep '?'` ... where's the question? If there is a question, I hope it can be asked in fewer words, because a wall of text greatly reduces the odds of an answer.

Comment: Read what I said carefully and see if it makes sense. That's the question - does the basis for my system make sense?. I know its long, but I can see no other means to make myself clear.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of points :

You don't mention how it will automatically perform the validaty checking.

I dont agree with this statement 
"This tells use that it is actually impossible to define most of English words using English alone"

An Ontolology should do presicely that - the tricky bit is to work out which one to use (there is a list of 18 top level Upper Ontologies at http://www.acutesoftware.com.au/aikif/ontology.html)

You need to clarify exactly what outputs this system is going to produce. I understand the idea of mapping the entities regulations ,etc but what are you going to do with this and how will the information be used.

Comment: Its not possible because those upper ontologies would need to be made from non-English concepts, or belong to a separate domain. Read the example of the man who is blind by birth: how'd you explain "red" to such man? "red" belongs to English, but its true definition as a combination of sensory experiences is not definable in English. An upper ontology does not necessarily consider this problem